# Material UI Portal + TypeScript - Types of property 'children' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, material-ui

Rendering a component with Material-UI Portal containing some material UI buttons.

```
<Portal container={this.myContainer}>
    <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Do something</Button>
    //some other buttons
</Portal>
```

This results in a typescript error

```
TypeScript error: Type '{ children: Element[]; container: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<PortalProps>'.
  Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
```

Material ui core v.3.9.0. Couldn't find any type library that solves this particular issue

Answer (score 0):

This error can be solved by wrapping the portal contents with a single div:

```
<Portal container={this.myContainer}>
    <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            Do something
        </Button>
         //some other buttons
    </div>
</Portal>
```